# Raphael JS - Parsing an SVG on the fly

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, svg, raphael

I found a neat SVG parser at http://bkp.ee/atirip/ which parses an SVG file and outputs it into javascript that uses the Raphael JS library (raphaeljs.com). You'll notice in the source code at http://bkp.ee/atirip/svg2rdemo.php :

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $("#c1").each(function(){  
    var c = Raphael(this, 190, 154, 0, 0);
    var g1 = c.set();
    ...
```

it creates variables like g1, g2, etc. But it also reuses these variables. I would like to create unique variables for each group. In my .ai file, I have named my groups and I would like to use these names to create the variable names.

Where in http://bkp.ee/atirip/f/svgToRaphaelParser.php.zip should I look to make this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some adjustments and squeezed one bug. You may download the new version.

Now you can call parser like this:

```
svgToRaphaelParser::parse(filename, containername, canvasname, groupname, shapename)
```

Without shapename it works like it used to: 
`svgToRaphaelParser::parse("f.svg", "this", "c", "g")` produces code you are already familiar.

To avoid reusing the same names, use different canvas and/or group name for different SVG files.

As a new feature, if you need to access to different shapes, use it like this:

```
svgToRaphaelParser::parse("f.svg", "this", "c", "g", "s")
```

Without shapename you receive this:

```
g1.push(c.path(...));
```

With shapename you receive this

```
var s1 = c.path(...);
g1.push(s1);
```

Comment: Ok, cool. That helps a lot! Thank you. It's not exactly what I was looking for. Here's some of my changes to your new parser: http://chrispaul.ws/svgToRaphaelParser.txt I wrote out the $attrs['id'] instead of using the passed in group name.

Comment: Where is the new version of this file?